# Select salvo mostra inputs através do ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um SELECT que abre determinados INPUTS.

FUNÇÃO QUE PEGA O ID DO SELECT E ABRE OS INPUTS.

```
     //Mostra div dos inputs do ipi 
  $('#selectProduto').change(function() {
    if ($('#selectProduto').val() == '1') {
      $('#nome_produto').show();
      $('#preco').show();
      $('#descricao').show();

    }
    if ($('#selectProduto').val() == '2') {
      $('#nome_produto').show();
      $('#preco').show();
      $('#descricao').show();

    }
      });
```

PRECISO CARREGAR NO ONLOAD DO JAVASCRIPT O ID QUE RECEBO VIA GET PELO PHP:

```
 $id_produto =   $_GET['id'];
```

https://jsfiddle.net/stfn5168/

VEJA A IMAGEM EXPLICANDO:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como você está recebendo os dados do banco?

Comment: Eu pego o ID via get, (exemplo produto.php?ID=1), dai preencho os campos via SELECT where id_produto=1, aí mostro os dados do select é igual o ID do produto, falta ele iniciar já com os os inputs que estão div display:none, virarem display:block, sendo o parametro o ID selecionado no select.

Comment: Você está fazendo a chamada via AJAX (Assincrona) ou no carregamento da página (Síncrona)

Comment: Veja o código no JSfiddle, só que não funciona no fiddel, aqui testei e funciona, mas você pode ver o código..código é simples..https://jsfiddle.net/stfn5168/

Comment: @miltoncamara, amigo, postei uma imagem auto explicativa do que estou precisando, o codigo pode pegar do jsfiddle como exemplo.

Comment: Tenta fazer o seguinte, no onload da página, você le o valor selecionado no seu select e chama a função para exibir os inputs. Vou fazer um exemplo no JSFIDDLER!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62700/discussion-between-miltoncamara-and-alh).

Comment: Ahhh outro detalhe, não está funcionando no Fiddler porque você não está carregando o jQuery! ;)

Comment: Olha este link que fiz https://jsfiddle.net/eo8ke6sg/

Comment: o seu também não funcionou no jsfiddle, mas o que preciso é que abra os INPUTS no ONLOAD que correspodem aquele ID, como no exemplo em js.

Comment: Estranho não ter funcionado, aqui está funcionando, só se o comportamento esperado por você não seja o que pensei! O que eu fiz, no evento load da página (Quando a página carrega) eu verifico o ID do item selecionado no SELECT e depois faço as comparações mostrando os campos na tela com o método SHOW ($(ELEMENTO).SHOW())

Comment: CONSEGUI UTILIZANDO A FUNCAO ONLOAD. OBRIGADO

Answer (score 0):

Faça assim:
     Ao carregar a página rode um ajax postando a id para um script php, em seguida recupere o valor da id em seu php pela variavel `$_GET['id']`, dentro dele faça um select no banco de dados filtrando pela id enviada, por último carregue as informações e imprima a resposta em json.

Em seu html :

```
<input type="hidden" id="produto_id"  value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />
```

Em seu javascript faça:

```
$(document).ready(function (){ 
    $.get("loadValue.php",{id : $('#produto_id').val()},function(data,status){
        if(data == 'success'){
            var arr = $.parseJSON(data);
            $('#nome_produto').val(arr.nome);
            $('#descricao').val(arr.texto);
        }
    });
});
```

> `$ (Documento).ready()`
>
> Uma página não pode ser manipulada com segurança até que o documento esteja "pronto". JQuery detecta esse estado de prontidão para você. O código incluído no interior
>
> `$( document ).ready()`
>
> só será executado uma vez que a página Document Object Model (DOM) esteja pronta para o código JavaScript para executar. O código incluído dentro
>
> `$( window ).on("load",function() { ... })`
>
> será executado uma vez que a página inteira (imagens ou iframes), e não apenas DOM, esteja pronta.

Agora se quiser apenas mostrar os campos inputs text ao carregar a página, a resposta está acima também serve. Basta carregar a id vinda por get em um campo do tipo hidden em seguida usando document.ready mostrar os campos de texto se o atributo value tiver valor.

Comment: Como ele já está na página de edição só precisa do onload!

Comment: Bem, eu tinha entendido que ele só tem a id do produto sem nome e descrição.

Comment: Verdade, talvez não tenha entendido este detalhe!

Comment: Esperar ele se manifestar.

Comment: olá, isso é dentro da página de edição que vem com o id pelo get..

Comment: preciso disso: ONLOAD verifica ID que recebe do $GET_["id"] e VERIFICA QUAL É O SELECT que está selecionado E MOSTRA OS inputs show(); .

Comment: Então, cria um campo do tipo input hidden quando abrir a pagina de edição, carrega o valor da id vinda por get no atributo value do input, em seguida a rotina acima executa após a leitura do html da página irá enviar uma requisição get para o backend para coletar as informações e recarrega-las no seu campo input text.